# Tracking url of external site launched in cordova-inappbrowser-plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm currently building an ionic app which is to be a wrapper for an external web application.  What I want to do is to be able to track the url being redirected to when the user changes location in the external web app.

In my main controller I have the following code.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($rootScope) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the Codova API
        var url = "https://external-site/";
        var target = "_self";
        var options = "location=no";
        var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
            console.log("loadstart");
        });
    }
});
```

When the page loads I don't get the event listener to fire or when the user changes locations in the external site.  I have tried pointing the target to _system and _blank which makes no difference for me.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I also need to track URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's my experience that all the events not always fires on all platforms. Try subscribing to all the events and print some debug info. Then test on different devices (iOS, android) and see what events are fired.

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function(e, event){console.log('start')};
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){console.log('stop')});
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function(e, event){console.log('err')});
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit', function(e, event){console.log('exit')});
```

btw: I'm using ngCordova here...

Comment: Thank you for the response but I'm not getting any of the events to fire when using the code above.

Comment: strange.  I'm using it with no problems. Are you on newest ionic, cordova and plugin? Are you testing in browser or device? 'loadstart' does not fire in browser. Try setting 'location=true' I think i saw some quirk with this causing some events to not fire at some point.

Comment: A quick test shows me that all events fires on my sony experia xa (regardless og location settings), im on ionic 1.3.2 and newest inAppBrowser plugin.

Comment: I was testing using the Ripple Emulator in VS 2015.  I've since tested on my device using ionic run android but with the same result :/

Answer (score 0):

very strange.. all I did was update ionic, run 'ionic start test blank' add the plugin modify app.js to this

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
      .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
          if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            var inAppBrowserRef;
            var target = "_self";
            var options = "location=no";

            inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://onesignal.com/', target, options);
            inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function () { console.log('start') });
            inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function () { console.log('stop') });
            inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loaderror', function () { console.log('err') });
          }
        });
      })
```

and then run 'ionic run android' and all events fires perf.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the issue isn't the fact that what I'm wrapping in ionic is infact another web app and perhaps when navigation occurs in there it doesn't emit the same events as the old web app was created for ios specifically using swift and xcode.